# Can I report the logcat file of my app to myself?

Tags: android-logcat, policy

I would like to record the logcat of my app and offer to the user the possibility to send it to me via email. I already have implemented all the flow and only the logcat tagged by me will be reported. I am aware that many personal information is output into the logcat, so I would like to know if there is any policy regarding to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself saying that the LOG_READ permissions is not longer supported in android 4.1, however you can read the logs that YOU have written without need any permission.
Conclusion: No problems on reporting your own logs to yourself